# Azure Speech Service CLI, using SSML Error code: 1007

Tags: azure, command-line-interface, ssml

I am using Azure Speech Service CLI, to synthesize with a SSML file, but I get following error

```
CANCELED: Reason=Error
CANCELED: ErrorCode=ConnectionFailure
CANCELED: ErrorDetails=Connection was closed by the remote host. Error code: 1007. Error details: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1. USP state: 3. Received audio size: 0bytes.
CANCELED: Did you update the subscription info?
```

I can use the synthesize with a text input and it works.

here is the SSML file I used (just the copy from doc):

```
<speak version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" xml:lang="en-US">
    <voice name="en-US-AriaRUS">
        This is the text that is spoken.
    </voice>
</speak>
```

My account is using "F0".

Answer (score 1):

You need to correct the speak node. You missed `xmlns:mstts="http://www.w3.org/2001/mstts"`

```
<speak xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" xmlns:mstts="http://www.w3.org/2001/mstts" xmlns:emo="http://www.w3.org/2009/10/emotionml" version="1.0" xml:lang="en-US">
    <voice name="en-US-AriaRUS">
        <prosody rate="0%" pitch="0%">
        This is the text that is spoken.
        </prosody>
    </voice>
</speak>
```